# How to fix this recursive addition?

Tags: recursion, prolog, addition, successor-arithmetics

I am new to logic programming and Prolog. The following Prolog program defines a predicate `add/3` for multiplying the first argument to the second argument, which results in the third argument, based on the equation *x* + *y* = *z* which is equivalent to (*x* − 1) + *y* = (*z* − 1):

```
add(0, Y, Y) :-
  number(Y).
add(X, Y, Z) :-
  number(X),
  number(Z),
  succ(U, X),
  succ(V, Z),
  add(U, Y, V).
```

But it this query, supposed to solve the equation 1 + 0 = z, does not return the expected result (`1`):

```
?- add(1, 0, Z).
   false.
```

How to fix this recursive addition?

Comment: The call to `number(Z)` will fail if Z is currently uninstantiated.

Comment: @gusbro I thought that `number(Z)` did actually instantiate `Z`. Because removing that literal yields an error: `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`.

Comment: `number(Z)` checks whether Z is a number. The error you are getting when you remove that call is from `succ(V, Z)` because both `V` and `Z` are uninstantiated in your sample call. You have to change your algorithm or use _CLP(fd)_

Comment: @gusbro And how would you change the algorithm (I don’t want to use CLP)?

Comment: You may swap the goals: first call `add(U, Y, V)`, then `succ(V, Z)`. That should work for queries where "X"and "Y" are instantiated.

Comment: @gusbro Swapping yields the same `false` result.

Comment: you have to remove the number(Z) as stated in my first comment

Comment: @gusbro Many thanks, that works! Could you write an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: As a beginner, rather use [tag:successor-arithmetics].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `false` is because the second clause of `add/3` calls `number(Z)` which only succeeds for ground number variables, but you are calling it with `Z` uninstantiated. `number/1` cannot be used as a generator.

Removing that goal will in turn give you another error, now in `succ(V, Z)` as you end up calling it with both variables uninstantiated and that predicate requires that at least one of its arguments be instantiated.

You can swap the goal with the recursive call to `add/3` so that `V` gets instantiated prior to calling `succ/2`. As `succ/2` already checks its arguments I will just remove the check for `X` being a number.

```
add(0, Y, Y) :-
  number(Y).
add(X, Y, Z) :- 
  succ(U, X),
  add(U, Y, V),
  succ(V, Z).
```

This procedure now should work for mode +,+,?. It will not work right for other modes. You may want to check *CLP(fd)*.

---

To make it work with at most 1 unbound variable within the three parameters you may split the recursive step on two different paths so as to ensure the first call to `succ/2` has 1 bound variable and the second call to `succ/2` has at least 1 bound variable.

```
add(0, Y, Y) :-
  number(Y).
add(X, Y, Z) :-
  (var(Z) -> L1-R1/L2-R2 = U-X/V-Z; L2-R2/L1-R1 = U-X/V-Z),
  succ(L1, R1),
  add(U, Y, V),
  succ(L2, R2).
```

which essentially selects an equation which can be evaluated with Prolog arithmetics.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it work for any modes (without CLP)?

Comment: You can easily make it work with queries that have 2 ground arguments. You just have to use the proper equation for the unbound argument. I get you want to do this as an exercise so you may try it yourself.

Comment: Also the usual recursive solution for this problem uses peano representation of successors and not actual integers. You may look for peano and addition on this site for similar questions.

Comment: So `add(X, Y, Z) :- succ(V, Z), add(U, Y, V), succ(U, X).` works for a single variable in the first position (e.g. `add(X, 2, 2)`), `add(X, Y, Z) :- succ(U, X), succ(V, Z), add(U, Y, V).` works for a single variable in the second position (e.g. `add(2, Y, 2).`), and `add(X, Y, Z) :- succ(U, X), add(U, Y, V), succ(V, Z).` works for a single variable in the third position (e.g. `add(2, 2, Z).`). How can I combine these clauses into a single rule to handle these three kinds of query?

Comment: @Maggyero: Edited the answer to show how you may combine those clauses onto a single rule that handles any case with at most 1 free variable

Comment: Thanks, I have learnt a lot. The key was the predicate `var/1` which tests whether its argument is a free variable. I think that an equivalent rule definition (but simpler for me to understand) is: `add(0, Y, Y). add(X, Y, Z) :- var(X) -> succ(V, Z), add(U, Y, V), succ(U, X); var(Y) -> succ(U, X), succ(V, Z), add(U, Y, V); succ(U, X), add(U, Y, V), succ(V, Z).`

Comment: Note that I also removed the predicate `number/1` in the first clause because it makes the results non symmetric (it returns `false` only for calls that bind the *second* parameter to a non-number ground argument) and it is useless (the last predicate `succ/2` already checks it since `V` is `Y` when `U` is `1`). –

Comment: By the way, your rule definition and my equivalent one work also for queries with *two* free variables, as long as the third parameter variable is bound, e.g. `add(X, Y, 3)`.

Comment: I have just found another equivalent rule definition that does not use the `->/2` predicate: `add(0, Y, Y). add(X, Y, Z) :- ground(X), ground(Z), succ(U, X), succ(V, Z), add(U, Y, V). add(X, Y, Z) :- ground(X), var(Z), succ(U, X), add(U, Y, V), succ(V, Z). add(X, Y, Z) :- ground(Z), var(X), succ(V, Z), add(U, Y, V), succ(U, X).`

Comment: @Maggyero you can usually "split" a clause that uses `->/2` by onto 2 separate clauses guarding each clause with the prerequisites needed to "enter" each clause. In your last comment, one clause guards for `X` and `Y` being ground, the second with `X` being ground and `Z` free, and the last one with `Z` being ground and `X` free. Note that if you "enter" any of those clauses then the other ones will not go through.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have just opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68614837/2326961) about recursive multiplication. This time I have a stack overflow issue when the query has *two* free variables in the first and second position. May I require your expertise again?